# Reflection - get property name

Tags: c#, reflection

I'd like to pass property names to a function without using of magic strings.

Something like:

```
Get<ObjectType>(x=>x.Property1);
```

where Property1 is a property of type ObjectType.

What would the method implementation look like ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This can be achieved using Expressions:

```
// requires object instance, but you can skip specifying T
static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> exp)
{
    return (((MemberExpression)(exp.Body)).Member).Name;
}

// requires explicit specification of both object type and property type
static string GetPropertyName<TObject, TResult>(Expression<Func<TObject, TResult>> exp)
{
    // extract property name
    return (((MemberExpression)(exp.Body)).Member).Name;
}

// requires explicit specification of object type
static string GetPropertyName<TObject>(Expression<Func<TObject, object>> exp)
{
    var body = exp.Body;
    var convertExpression = body as UnaryExpression;
    if(convertExpression != null)
    {
        if(convertExpression.NodeType != ExpressionType.Convert)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property expression.", "exp");
        }
        body = convertExpression.Operand;
    }
    return ((MemberExpression)body).Member.Name;
}
```

Usage:

```
var x = new ObjectType();
// note that in this case we don't need to specify types of x and Property1
var propName1 = GetPropertyName(() => x.Property1);
// assumes Property2 is an int property
var propName2 = GetPropertyName<ObjectType, int>(y => y.Property2);
// requires only object type
var propName3 = GetPropertyName<ObjectType>(y => y.Property3);
```

**Update:** fixed `GetPropertyName<TObject>(Expression<Func<TObject, object>> exp)` for properties returning value types.

Comment: Is there any chance to get it working without creating an instance first and without the empty brackets ? Just (x=>x.Prop1)

Comment: Added an overload for that case (code is the same though, and idea is already expressed in Darin's answer).

Comment: there is one small problem, I have to specify the property type (int,string..)  Can be this handled ?

Comment: added 3rd overoad which handles this

Comment: @xeondev The third overload worked for as it was posted... how were you calling it, that it was failing for you?

Comment: @AspNyc Well, I can't reproduce, probably it was my fault, so deleted the comment...

Comment: The third overload crashes because sometimes exp.Body is of type UnaryExpression. It has to be modified to handle that case. Or just use the second overload which does not have this issue.

Comment: Mind you `Func<TObject, object>` won't support boolean or enumeration properties.

Answer (score 8):

```
class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var result = Get<Foo, string>(x => x.Bar);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    static string Get<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression)
    {
        var me = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (me != null)
        {
            return me.Member.Name;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```